# Numpy: Faster computation of triple nested loops involving sum reductions

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, gpu, jit

My goal is to compute the following nested loop efficiently,

```
Ab = np.random.randn(1000, 100)    
Tb = np.zeros((100, 100, 100))

for i in range(d):
    for j in range(d):
        for k in range(d):
            Tb[i, j, k] = np.sum(Ab[:, i] * Ab[:, j] * Ab[:, k])
```

I found a faster approach to do the nested loop by looping over the combinations only:

```
for i,j,k in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(np.arange(100), 3):
    Abijk = np.sum(Ab[:, i] * Ab[:, j] * Ab[:, k])

    Tb[i, j, k] = Abijk
    Tb[i, k, j] = Abijk

    Tb[j, i, k] = Abijk
    Tb[j, k, i] = Abijk

    Tb[k, j, i] = Abijk
    Tb[k, i, j] = Abijk
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this ?

I am hoping for a way that can take advantage of Numpy's Blas, Numba's JIT, or Pytorch GPU implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could directly use the iterators as [`einsum` string notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) with NumPy's built-in  [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). Thus, the solution would be with a single `einsum` call -

```
Tb = np.einsum('ai,aj,ak->ijk',Ab,Ab,Ab)
```

**Approach #2**

We could use a combination of `broadcasted elementwise-multiplication` and then `np.tensordot` or `np.matmul` for the all the `sum-reductions`.

Hence, get the broadcasted elementwise-multiplications with again `einsum` or explicit dimension-extension and `broadcasting` -

```
parte1 = np.einsum('ai,aj->aij',Ab,Ab)
parte1 = (Ab[:,None,:]*Ab[:,:,None]
```

Then, `tensordot` or `np.matmul` -

```
Tb = np.tensordot(parte1,Ab,axes=((0),(0)))
Tb = np.matmul(parte1.T, Ab) # Or parte1.T @ Ab on Python 3.x
```

Thus, there are a total of four variants possible with this second approach.

#### Runtime test

```
In [140]: d = 100
     ...: m = 1000
     ...: Ab = np.random.randn(m,d)

In [148]: %%timeit  # original faster method
     ...: d = 100
     ...: Tb = np.zeros((d,d,d))
     ...: for i,j,k in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(np.arange(100), 3):
     ...:     Abijk = np.sum(Ab[:, i] * Ab[:, j] * Ab[:, k])
     ...: 
     ...:     Tb[i, j, k] = Abijk
     ...:     Tb[i, k, j] = Abijk
     ...: 
     ...:     Tb[j, i, k] = Abijk
     ...:     Tb[j, k, i] = Abijk
     ...: 
     ...:     Tb[k, j, i] = Abijk
     ...:     Tb[k, i, j] = Abijk
1 loop, best of 3: 2.08 s per loop

In [141]: %timeit np.einsum('ai,aj,ak->ijk',Ab,Ab,Ab)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.08 s per loop

In [142]: %timeit np.tensordot(np.einsum('ai,aj->aij',Ab,Ab),Ab,axes=((0),(0)))
     ...: %timeit np.tensordot(Ab[:,None,:]*Ab[:,:,None],Ab,axes=((0),(0)))
     ...: %timeit np.matmul(np.einsum('ai,aj->ija',Ab,Ab), Ab)
     ...: %timeit np.matmul(Ab.T[None,:,:]*Ab.T[:,None,:], Ab)


10 loops, best of 3:  56.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3:  59.2 ms per loop
 1 loop,  best of 3: 673   ms per loop
 1 loop,  best of 3: 670   ms per loop
```

Fastest ones seem to be the `tensordot` based ones. Thus, getting `35x+` speedup over the faster one-loopy `itertools` based method.

Comment: `tensordot` has an insane improvement over `einsum`, Thanks for these great algorithms!

Comment: @Curious I could not run your itertools based one at my end. If it's not too much work for you, could you let me know the timing numbers with it and how it compares against the tensordot based ones? I am always curious about performance numbers :)

Comment: @Divaker You probably got the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` when you ran the method with `itertools` I fixed the code above, it should have been 
`itertools.combinations_with_replacement(np.arange(100), 3)` instead of `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(100, 3)` :)

Comment: @Curious Yup, that's it! Added timings with that one too for one-place comparison of all.

Comment: I am still in shock at the amount of speed improvement! I wonder why `np.einsum('ai,aj,ak->ijk',Ab,Ab,Ab)` is not as fast as `np.tensordot(Ab[:,None,:]*Ab[:,:,None],Ab,axes=((0),(0)))`. I would have thought that they both internally use the same efficient implementation written in numpy's backend.

Comment: @Curious Well `einsum` uses plain C codes, while tensordot leverages much faster BLAS. `einsum` is apparently slow when it needs to process more than 2-dim data (from my experience working with it) and in this case it goes to 4-dim(if you consider the entire expansion before sum-reduction), which I am guessing is simply the memory congestion involved.